# Connecting on already running browser with Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge

I would like some help to see if there is a way around this problem.
I'm testing to make a script that can connect to the browser that is launched by the user.

### **What I can do with success:**

I CAN connect to a browser that is launched by this command:

`"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" --remote-debugging-port=9244 --user-data-dir="C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Plocha\záložky\msedge1"`

The command must have a specified user data directory which must be different from the basic user edge data. (different from this: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data)

---

### **What I can't manage to do:**

The goal is to connect to the browser launched by the user. So I was trying to find the port of edge processes from this command: `netstat -AB`. I copy the IP address that was with the process name: msedge.exe and pasted it into the script. It thought for a minute and it came up with this result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGL4d.png

---

### **The script:**

```py
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.edge.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.edge.service import Service

edge_options = Options()
edge_options.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress","127.0.0.1:55718")

edge_options.use_chromium = True
s = Service('C:/Users/WDAGUtilityAccount/Downloads/edgedriver_win64/msedgedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Edge(service = s, options = edge_options)

print(driver.title)
```

Comment: What error do you get with this script?

Comment: The error is in the link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGL4d.png

Comment: @Tom Part of the error message: 
```selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot connect to microsoft edge at [fe80::edb1:701d:3734:2291%10]:55718
from chrome not reachable```

Comment: `--remote-debugging-port=9244`  is significant because it tells Edge to allow remote debugging. What do you mean by "the user" in The goal is to connect to the browser launched by the user?

Comment: I mean manually (by Icon) not by command. In other words, I would like to access tabs that I commonly use.

Comment: @Tom If there is a way to change debug options in the process of running the app Im down to go for it.

Comment: Yes, you can only connect to running Edge instance when the instance is launched with remote-debugging-port. Only specify this, it knows which debugger server to connect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to bind to the Edge browser's devtools protocol without explicitly starting an Edge instance with your debugging arguments applied. At the time of writing, I cannot find a way to apply these settings to Edge by default.

However, it could be worth worth adding your debugging arguments `--remote-debugging-port=9244 --user-data-dir="C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Plocha\záložky\msedge1"` to the Windows Shortcut in:

`C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`

Microsoft Edge (Right-Click) > Properties > Target (append your debugging arguments.) Every time you start edge through this shortcut, your debugger will be enabled.

Please note, for what it's worth, this is called remote-debugging because it is designed to *debug*. Please consider the risks of exposing your day-to-day production browsing data on an unauthenticated network port.